# Delphi Controls for Editing Key/Value Pairs?

Tags: delphi, user-interface, delphi-xe, vcl

What Delphi visual control or combination of controls do you suggest for editing, adding and deleting key/value pairs (strings)?

Comment: You mean something like the object inspector but with editable property names?

Comment: @David: yeah, something like that. Doesn't have to be editable inplace.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try the [`TValueListEditor`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ValEdit.TValueListEditor) component (to allow to the component edit and delete the keys you must set in the [`KeyOptions`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ValEdit.TValueListEditor.KeyOptions) property the [`keyEdit`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ValEdit.TKeyOptions) and [`keyAdd`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ValEdit.TKeyOptions) values).

Comment: To see it in action, the `Strings` property editor dialog of a ValueListEditor has a ValueListEditor in it.

Comment: @RRUZ: thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for. Didn't know about this component at all. Is there any way to customize the in-place edit (background, font)? (+1)

Comment: @smasher, sure you can customize this component, check the `OnDrawCell` event.

Comment: @RRUZ: I want to customize the in-place edit, not the control itself. I don't see how `OnDrawCell` helps here.

Comment: `TProtectedHackInplaceEditList(ValueListEditor1.Controls[0]).Font.Color:=clRed;`

Comment: Is there something built in to this control for picking from a list of options?

Comment: @jrodenhi: look at the `TValueListEditor.OnGetPickList` event, and the `TItemProp.EditStyle` and `TItemProp.PickList` properties.